# Is there a way of ignoring files in the watch task of boot-clj?

Tags: vim, clojurescript, boot-clj

I'm using boot in a clojurescript project and the development flow is pretty smooth so far. But there's one thing that's bothering me.

I use VIM as my editor and it creates temporary files for its buffers, the famous files named with `~` in the end. Every time I edit a file vim creates the temporary file for its buffer and as I'm using the built-in task `watch` of boot, it triggers the reload even though I've not saved any real file.

This is my boot task definition:

```
(deftask dev                                                     
   "Launch Immediate Feedback Development Environment"
   []
   (comp
     (serve :dir "target" :reload true)
     (watch)
     (reload)
     (cljs-repl)
     (cljs)
     (sass :source-maps true :output-dir "styles")
     (target :dir #{"target"})))
```

I would like to configure the `watch` task to ignore any file ending with `~` so the reload will be triggered only when I save some meaningful file. Is it possible? Is there any other solution?

Comment: Most file system watchers (entr, fswatch, chokidar, etc.) already have that covered. You should tell the maintainers of that tool to take a look at what others are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been mentioned in [Boot wiki](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/For-Vim-Users). As far as I know the `watch` task doesn't support ignoring such files and the wiki describes a workaround for it by changing the location of vim's backup files.